# Arrow of time as the result of a feedback loop that stabilizes an inheret unstable reversible time

Tags: entropy, time, stability, arrow-of-time

I am searching to find some literature on idea i am having, regarding the "arrow of time".

The main idea is an expansion of the main theme of an Asimov  sci-fi novel, where he postulates that a time machine is impossible because the invention of one, would render the "time line" unstable, and the only stable time line would emerge only if the time machine had never been invented.

So,my idea was think, on the same line, in a microscopic level. That is, to imagine a "base" state were time is **reversible**, rendering the time **line unstable**, and then, to understand the arrow of time as the result of the only possible state  where the **time-line stabilizes itself** by denying the a backward time travel
In a sense, to imagine the **actual time** as the result of a feedback stabilized "base time" that is reversible but unstable.
I was wondering if someone has expanded on some kind of such theory.

Comment: This seems to be off-topic on this site as it does not concern mainstream physics, but a personal theory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading Kip Thorne's book 'Black Holes and Time Warps', where he discusses how wormholes might be used to create time machines, but one of the problems with them is that the loop in time causes particles to spontaneously appear out of nowhere and circulate around the loop, the explosion of energy (maybe) being enough to destroy the wormholes before they can formed.

This is also reminiscent of Feynman's sum-over-histories approach to quantum mechanics, where all possible trajectories have to be considered, including ones that loop back through time, but that all these have incoherent phases and cancel out, leaving only the expected forwards-in-time straight line motion. A good introductory source for that is Feynman's book "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter".

However, neither of these explains the *arrow* of time, which is not related to microscopic physics but to boundary conditions directed towards the distant past. The microscopic laws of motion are time-reversible, so we can't ever use microscopic physics to *create* low entropy inside a region of spacetime, we can only import it from the outside. And the only place we find it outside is in the distant past, at or near the start of the universe (we don't know how or why), so low entropy is always found on the past boundary.